# PyQT4 QWidget must receive 'close' signal twice before closing

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

I'm writing a PyQT4 (4.11) program that performs a long slow task which ideally needs a progress bar. The program works almost perfectly if I don't use threads, sub-classing a QWidget which only contains a QProgressBar and a layout. Instantiating this sub-class as `form`, I can call `form.show()` to put it on screen, and then my long slow loop can update the progress by calling `form.progressbar.setValue(progress)`. There are two problems with this:

1. if the user tries to interact with the window they get 'not responding' messages from the windows manager/OS desktop process. This is because events are not being processed.
2. because events aren't being processed, the user can't cancel the long slow loop by closing the window.

So I tried making the long slow loop run in a separate thread, using a signal to update the progress bar. I overrode the closeEvent of my QWidget so that it can cancel interaction with the hardware device (all wrapped in mutexes so the device communication doesn't get out of sync). Again, this almost works. If I cancel, the application quits. If I leave it to run to completion though, I have to close the window manually (i.e. click the close icon or press alt-f4), even though I'm sending a close signal to the QWidget. As you can see in the code below there are some complications, since the app can't close immediately if cancelled, because it has to wait for some hardware clean up to happen. Here is a minimal version of my code

```
import sys
import os
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_ProgressBarDialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, on_close=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.center()

        #on_close is a function that is called to cancel
        #the long slow loop
        self.on_close = on_close

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def setupUi(self, ProgressBarDialog):
        ProgressBarDialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ProgressBarDialog"))
        ProgressBarDialog.resize(400, 33)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(ProgressBarDialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(ProgressBarDialog)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("progressBar"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        self.retranslateUi(ProgressBarDialog)

        #This allows the long slow loop to update the progress bar
        QtCore.QObject.connect(
            self,
            QtCore.SIGNAL("updateProgress"),
            self.progressBar.setValue
        )

        #Catch the close event so we can interrupt the long slow loop
        QtCore.QObject.connect(
            self,
            QtCore.SIGNAL("closeDialog"),
            self.closeEvent
        )

        #Repaint the window when the progress bar's value changes  
        QtCore.QObject.connect(
            self.progressBar,
            QtCore.SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"),
            self.repaint
        )
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ProgressBarDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, ProgressBarDialog):
        ProgressBarDialog.setWindowTitle("Please Wait")

    def closeEvent(self, event, force=False):
        if self.on_close is not None and not force:
            self.on_close()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
filename = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
    None,
    "Save as",
    os.getcwd(),
    "Data files: (*.dat)"
))

loop_mutex = thread.allocate_lock()
cancelled = False
can_quit = False
result = None

def cancel_download():
    global cancelled
    if can_quit:
        return
    if QtGui.QMessageBox.question(
            None,
            'Cancel Download',
            "Are you sure you want to cancel the download?",
            QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No,
            QtGui.QMessageBox.No) == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        with loop_mutex:
            selected_device.cancelDownload()
            cancelled = True
        while not can_quit:
            time.sleep(0.25)

form = ProgressBarDialog.Ui_ProgressBarDialog(cancel_download)
form.setWindowTitle("Please Wait")
form.progressBar.setMaximum(1000)
form.progressBar.setValue(0)
form.show()

def long_slow_loop(mutex, filename):
    global can_quit, result
    progress = 0

    temp_binary_file = open(filename, "wb")

    #The iterator below does the actual work of interacting with a
    #hardware device, so I'm locking around the "for" line. I must
    #not fetch more data from the device while a cancel command is
    #in progress, and vice versa
    mutex.acquire()
    for data in ComplexIteratorThatInteractsWithHardwareDevice():
        mutex.release()
        temp_binary_file.write(datablock)
        progress += 1
        form.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("updateProgress"), progress)
        mutex.acquire()
        if cancelled:
            break
    mutex.release()
    result = not cancelled
    temp_binary_file.close()
    if cancelled:
        os.unlink(filename)
    #having set can_quit to True the following emission SHOULD
    #cause the app to exit by closing the last top level window
    can_quit = True
    form.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("closeDialog"), QtGui.QCloseEvent(), True)

thread.start_new_thread(do_dump, (loop_mutex, filename))
app.exec_()
if result == True:
    QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Success', "Save to disk successful", QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
```

Comment: Signals are not the same as events. You cannot send an event using a signal. But in any case, if you want to close the window, why not just call `form.close()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the secret is to use a QThread which emits some signals when the thread exits. Either "finished" or "terminated" depending on whether the exit was normal or abnormal. Here's some code

```
import sys
import os
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_ProgressBarDialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, process, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.thread = process
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.center()
        self.thread.start()

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def setupUi(self, ProgressBarDialog):
        ProgressBarDialog.setObjectName("ProgressBarDialog")
        ProgressBarDialog.resize(400, 33)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(ProgressBarDialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(ProgressBarDialog)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        self.retranslateUi(ProgressBarDialog)

        #Close when the thread finishes (normally)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(
            self.thread,
            QtCore.SIGNAL("finished()"),
            self.close
        )

        #Close when the thread is terminated (exception, cancelled etc)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(
            self.thread,
            QtCore.SIGNAL("terminated()"),
            self.close
        )

        #Let the thread update the progress bar position
        QtCore.QObject.connect(
            self.thread,
            QtCore.SIGNAL("updateProgress"),
            self.progressBar.setValue
        )

        #Repaint when the progress bar value changes
        QtCore.QObject.connect(
            self.progressBar,
            QtCore.SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"),
            ProgressBarDialog.repaint
        )

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ProgressBarDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, ProgressBarDialog):
        ProgressBarDialog.setWindowTitle("Please Wait")

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.thread.exit_status == self.thread.RUNNING:
            if QtGui.QMessageBox.question(None, 'Cancel Download', "Are you sure you want to cancel the download?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No) == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
                if self.thread.exit_status == self.thread.RUNNING:
                    self.thread.exiting = True
                    while self.thread.exiting:
                        time.sleep(0.25)
                elif self.thread.exit_status == self.thread.SUCCESS:
                    self.thread.exit_status = self.thread.CANCELLED
            else:
                if self.thread.exit_status == self.thread.RUNNING:
                    event.ignore()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
filename = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
    None,
    "Save as",
    os.getcwd(),
    "Data files: (*.dat)"
))

class DeviceDataStreamHandler(QtCore.QThread):
    RUNNING = 1
    SUCCESS = 0
    FAILURE = -1
    CANCELLED = -2

    class CancelledError(Exception):
        pass

    def __init__(self, parent = None, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exiting = False
        self.exit_status = DeviceDataStreamHandler.RUNNING
        self.device = device
        self.filename = filename

    def run(self):
        progress = 0
        try:
            temp_binary_file = open(self.filename, "wb")
            #getDataStream is an interator returing strings
            for data in self.device.getDataStream():
                temp_binary_file.write(data)
                progress += 1
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("updateProgress"), progress)
                if self.exiting:
                    raise DeviceDataStreamHandler.CancelledError()
            self.exit_status = DeviceDataStreamHandler.SUCCESS
        except DeviceDataStreamHandler.CancelledError:
            self.exit_status = DeviceDataStreamHandler.CANCELLED
            self.device.cancelDownload()
        except Exception as E:
            self.exit_status = DeviceDataStreamHandler.FAILURE
            self.error_details = str(E)
        finally:
            temp_binary_file.close()
            if self.exit_status == DeviceDataStreamHandler.CANCELLED:
                os.unlink(filename)
        self.exiting = False

class HardwareDeviceObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #initialises comms with a hardware device
        self.event_count = 0
        self.capture = False

    def startCapture(self):
        self.capture = True

    def cancelDownload():
        self.capture = False

    def read(self):
        #returns a string sent from the device
        time.sleep(1)
        self.event_count += 1
        return self.event_count

    def getDataStream(self):
        class DataStreamIterator(object):
            def __init__(self, ds, max_capture_count = 100):
                self.ds = ds
                self.capture_count = 0
                self.max_capture_count = max_capture_count

            def __iter__(self):
                return self

            def next(self):
                #return string received from device
                if self.ds.capture and self.capture_count < self.max_capture_count:
                    self.capture_count += 1
                    return self.ds.read()
                else:
                    raise StopIteration()

        self.startCapture()
        return DataStreamIterator(self)

capture = DeviceDataStreamHandler(device = HardwareDeviceObject(), filename = filename)
form = ProgressBarDialog.Ui_ProgressBarDialog(capture)
form.setWindowTitle("Dumping sessions")
form.progressBar.setMaximum(100) #expect 100 outputs from the device
form.progressBar.setValue(0)
form.show()

app.exec_()
if capture.exit_status == DeviceDataStreamHandler.SUCCESS:
    QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Success', "Save to disk successful", QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
elif capture.exit_status == DeviceDataStreamHandler.FAILURE:
    QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error interacting with device', "{}".format(capture.error_details), QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
```